# SubArray selection in swift

Tags: python, arrays, swift, sub-array

I want to do a sub-array selection Python-like (`ArraySlice`) in Swift.

This is working for me, but I know it's not nice. To make it work I used `.suffix` embedded to `.prefix` method.  I'm wondering if there's an easier or cleaner method to accomplish this:

```swift
let startIndex = 3
let endIndex = 7

let newPoints = Array(points.suffix(points.count - startIndex).prefix(endIndex - startIndex + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Array Slice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice)

Example implementation:

```
startIndex = 3
endIndex = 7

let slice = points[startindex...endindex]
```

But you should read the documentation on this. `ArraySlice` is a look into the array and keeping it alive for a long time is discouraged.

Comment: Oh I was only looking into the Array's properties/methods.. didn't know it had that type as well. That'll work great. Thanks!